# macro to copy values to bottom of range

Tags: excel

1. cells A1:D1 contain variable calculations
2. cells below A1:D1 will contain values from cell A1:D1 
   calculations
3. I will name A1:D1 - range01
4. I would like a macro to copy values from A1:D1 (range01) to the 
   next available row below in the same columns. So 1st values 
   will go to A2:D2, 2nd vlaues to by A3:D3, etc.
5. This routine will be nested inside a looping macro.
   Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately Excel VBA provides a fairly convinient "function" to get the next free space

```
Sub copyToFreeSpace()
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Dim freeRow As Long

Set xSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TABLENAME") 'Set the Worksheet here
Set copyRange = xSheet.Range("A1:D1") 'Define Range
freeRow = xSheet.Cells(xSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Get "free row"
xSheet.Range(xSheet.Cells(freeRow, 1), xSheet.Cells(freeRow, 4)) = copyRange.Value 'Copy value from above range
End Sub
```

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you poiting out my mistake - I edited my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Value transfers are faster! Also, since this will be inside a loop, your last free row will need to be readjusted each time otherwise you will continuously paste over the same values.

Here is an example code that loops 48 times while incrementing the last row

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ValueTransfer()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim rCopy As Range, LR As Long, i As Long

Set rCopy = ws.Range("A1:D1")
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

For i = 2 To 50
    ws.Range("A" & LR).Resize(1, 4).Value = rCopy.Value
    LR = LR + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

---

As an added bonus, you can make this  more dynamic by changing the `Resize` function to

```
`.Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count, rCopy.Columns.Count)
```